# Dont understand while loop syntax

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I need help with an input driven loop, meaning the user enters two values and the sum,difference,product,quotient and remainder are printed until user enters a zero for the second value. I don't understand how to write the while loop what variable am I testing

Here's a sample:

```
enter two integers: 19 7
sum of 19 and 7 is 26
difference of 19 and 7 is 12 
etc..
```

Comment: You should be able to get many examples if you search. Anyways, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an infinite loop with a `break` condition will do the trick. Here is how

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
  {
    int a , b;
    while( 1 )
      {
        std :: cout << "\nEnter two integers :" ;
        std :: cin >> a >> b ;
        if ( b == 0 )
           break;
        std :: cout << "\nSum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << a + b ;
        std :: cout << "\nDifference of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << a - b ;
        std :: cout << "\nProduct of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << a * b ;
        std :: cout << "\nQuotient when " << a << " is divided by " << b << " is " << a / b ;
        std :: cout << "\nRemainder when " << a << " is divided by " << b << " is " << a % b ;
      }
    return 0;
  }
```

You just have to use `break` if `b == 0`. When `break` is encountered, the program exits from the loop. ( in case you are a total noob and don't know how to use break, read this [break](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_break_statement.htm) )

`while( 1 )` is an infinite loop, and the program will only exit the loop when `break` is encountered.

Also remember that `%` won't work on floats. If you want floats, then you will have to use [std::fmod()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) ( `std :: fmod( a , b );` returns the remainder when `a` is divided by `b`, where `a` and `b` are floats or doubles, it is included in the `<cmath>` header file ) .

Comment: I would highly appreciate it if someone tells me on how to improve this post or if there's something wrong with it .

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're a beginner...and you are using `<iostream>`. If you are using something else e.g. `<cstdio>` then comment and I'll change the code, but it goes something like this: (for multiplying numbers, you can figure out the rest :D)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int num1;
    int num2;
    while (true){
         cout << "Enter some numbers";
         cin >> num1 >> num2;
         cout << "Product is " << num1*num2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Use an infinite loop and break the loop on your own condition.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int num1, num2;
    while (1){
         cout << "\nEnter some numbers ";
         cin >> num1 >> num2;
         if(num2==0)
               break;
         cout << "Product is " << num1*num2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: compile this and you will instantly find the reason it was downvoted.

Comment: I've not compiled it and since working in python for a long time, got the habit of `True` and `False`. And I'm not good with c++ too. Just gave the logic.

Comment: That wasn't the problem with it. Compile it. You should have easily noticed the problem.

Comment: @ArunA.S Thanks. This is my 1st compilation of a c++ program in linux environment. :-) Now it's working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Good thing that you finally realized the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in several ways. For example

```
while ( true )
{
   std::cout << "Enter two integer numbers: ";

   int first;
   int second = 0;

   std::cin >> first >> second;

   if ( second == 0 ) break;

   std::cout << "sum of " << first 
                << " and " << second 
                << " is " << first + second;
                << std::endl;

   std::cout << "difference of " << first 
                << " and " << second 
                << " is " << first - second;
                << std::endl;

   // and other outputs if they are required
}
```